# Why does the neural network stops at a certain loss and does not converge with a big learning rate?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions

When increasing the learning rate of an neural network I expect a divergence of the gradient because the gradient moves further in every step of the learning rate which should result in endless cost values. In [this](https://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=xor&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=10&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=5,3,8,8,2,2&seed=0.42487&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=true&ySquared=true&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false) neural network simulation I configured the learning rate to $10$ (see image) and expect an divergence in loss because of that but the loss stops at a certain value. Why is this the case and the loss/cost function doesn't diverge? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the definition of loss. Try regression.

[image]